# Use Powershell to copy Long Filename files

Tags: powershell, recursion, xcopy

Unfortunatly for me we have a legacy file system which has been around since the dinosaurs roamed. Over time, files have been moved/copied to a location which has generated a folder + file structure which is too long to simply copy from one location to another. (long file name)

What I see as a solution is to use powershell to map a drive to each file location, copy it then recurse for each.
e.g. 
net use w: \newlocation\
net use x: \silly long file path\folder1\
xcopy x:\file.txt w:\folder1

then use for each to copy the same structure as it was originally.
I know it seems long winded but I cannot think of a better way forward. I've tried Robocopy which is supposed to avoid this problem but through much testing.. Nope. Still fails to copy.

Can you please suggest a good method for doing this?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the dicussion at http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/delete-old-files-script-error-path-too-long/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but you can try the program called Beyond Compare which should work for you.

Honestly, I didn't spend too much time with it as it has bunch of options but I know people who successfully use it every day for files with long file names.